# Python Twisted pip package not compatible with Python3

Tags: python, pip, twisted

I am trying to use create an authoritative server using twisted names. I was using python 3.6 and installed using `pip3 install twisted`, but it looks like pip is not updated with python3 versions. Specifically, pip has [twisted 20.3](https://pypi.org/project/Twisted/20.3.0/), but 20.3 is written for Python2. The file `authority.py` uses python2 syntax in 20.3 version - [Line 308](https://github.com/twisted/twisted/blob/twisted-20.3.0/src/twisted/names/authority.py#L308). Any idea about when the pip package is going to be updated? Is it recommended to use python2 (and version 20.3) or install from source by cloning the repository?

Comment: This is the first paragraph on the README page on Github. Twisted is an event-based framework for internet applications, supporting Python 3.5+. It includes modules for many different purposes, including the following.... It clearly states that it supports your python version. So could you please add info, like what is wrong are you getting any errors?

Comment: Sure. I installed twisted using `pip3 install twisted` and downloaded the [example zone file](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/names/howto/names.html#creating-an-authoritative-server). I tried running `twistd -n dns --pyzone example-domain.com`. That command gave the error `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iterkeys'` and that was due to Line 308 mentioned above.